# Goats in Brokeback Mountain

Tags: brokeback-mountain

I have heard the reason the movie brokeback mountain take place at Big Horn Mountains is because of the Goats that lives on the mountain actually are homosexual (sorry if I did not use the correct terms here).  Is it just a rumor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Very much a rumour**.

From [USA Today](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/travel/destinations/2006-01-30-brokeback-tourism_x.htm):

> Coon [Wyoming Business Council spokesman] said Ang Lee, the director of Brokeback Mountain, toured much of
>   the eastern Big Horn Mountains and several nearby towns when scouting
>   locations for the film. *But because of budget concerns, Lee shot the
>   film in Canada.*
>
> Financial incentives have drawn many film companies to Canada, which
>   has built a $5 billion film industry in the process. Because of the
>   high amount of production there already, companies can hire local
>   crews instead of bringing them from elsewhere, cheapening the overall
>   price of the project.

It's also worth considering these two different responses by Ang Lee, the director, in interviews.

First, from [MovieWeb](http://www.movieweb.com/news/ang-lee-talks-brokeback-mountain):

> The setting plays an important role in your films. This film is an
>   epic cowboy movie set in Wyoming. Was this another thing that sold you
>   aside from the romance?
>
> Ang Lee: Yes, I think that sold me and helped the romance. I think
>   great romance needs great obstacles and textures. Romance and love are
>   abstract ideas, an illusion. How do you make that? I think, most of
>   the time, obstacles help build the romance. It helps to envision and
>   make it feel real to you. I think that mixture is ultimately very
>   interesting because they're very macho, but romance is usually soft.
>   That strange mixture was very fresh and helped me to grope into what
>   love is.

Second, from [AboutFilm](http://www.aboutfilm.com/movies/b/brokebackmountain/lee.htm):

> Question: You traveled with [screenwriter] Larry McMurtry to Western
>   locations while scouting the movie. What surprised you about Western
>   people or locations that you didn't know before?
>
> Lee: The location, we have seen it. We have traveled through it or
>   [seen it in] a movie. I think it was more the people. Of course, they
>   are always nice people. They are just like everybody here, except they
>   are nicer, and I felt guilty that I was going to do a tough movie
>   about them. [Laughs.] Something struck me, [with my] fresh eyes. Sorry
>   to say—[the] eccentric[ity]. You go to a bar and just see the things
>   that they hang up. I can't believe the things they hang up inside and
>   outside of bars. So imaginary. I don't know how else to put it. Of
>   course that will annoy a lot of Westerners, because [they'll say], “We
>   have a lot of normal people.” There are two sides. One is like that.
>   It's like [they] don't want [you] to go into their territory. I saw a
>   sign in Wyoming—a “No Trespassing” sign. And it says, “Trespassers
>   will be shot. Survivors will be shot again.” [Laughs.] Some characters
>   are like that. If they hear you're coming with the Wyoming film
>   commissioners, [they want] nothing to do with the state.
>
> But they are also very nice people, because they are lonely and when
>   you go to the countryside and want [friendliness], you can't shut them
>   down. They keep talking and talking and talking, and they have this
>   Wyoming lazy town kind of thing. You have to pay a lot of attention.
>   They have this easy tone. Very slow, very easy. Relax, and we'll talk
>   about something really tragic. One tragic story after another—the most
>   miserable things. It's just on and on, slowly. And you have to pay
>   attention. They take long pauses. So, I learned a lot like that. Of
>   course, [if] you watch Larry McMurtry you learn. He's the epitome.

These suggest the primary reason for filming there is that it had beautiful locations, friendly people and was a traditional "macho", cowboy area - a perfect backdrop considering the story.

Comment: Very detailed explanation on why the location is actually be chosen, thanks!